# Jquery Easy Slider on Open cart v.1.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opencart

I'm using Jquery Easy Slider on Opencart v.1.5.1
http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

What I'm trying to do is use easy slider for the best seller section of my homepage.
I've copied all files required but I'm having problems with it.

1. Only 1 image shows when it slides (I think it's because of the UL width but i'm not sure how to set it)
2. the next and previous arrows are out of place.

Here's the url of the site: http://goo.gl/f4Xi0

Comment: Okay I fixed number 1.. my only problem is number 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

span id="nextBtn", its "position" is set to "absolute", right? So its parent div should be set to "position:relative", otherwise its position will be relative to the whole document.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `.box-product { position: relative; }` and then work your way forward with the css to adjust `#prevBtn` and `#nextBtn` `left` values to put the arrows where you want them.

http://www.csspivot.com/p3rn7 - This is after the `.box-product { position: relative; }` ( note that `#prevBtn` is still lost but adjust those `left` values and it will come back.. something like 0px for that maybe and something like 600px for `#nextBtn` )